# I'm facing the DateTime merging issue in SQL level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck in pplying aggregation in the `Date` field I know I can't use the `Sum` function. Is there any other way we can achieve this kind of thing?

I'll try with group query but not getting the same output.

Below the query.

```
SELECT  
        [S].[SessionID]
        ,[S].[Title]        
        ,[SZL].[StartTime]
        ,[SZL].[EndTime]
        ,[dbo].[datetime_difference]([SZL].[StartTime],[SZL].[EndTime]) [Difference]        
    FROM    
        [dbo].[SessionZoomLog] [SZL] (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[ZoomMeetingLog] [ZML] (NOLOCK) ON [ZML].[ZoomMeetingLogID] = [SZL].[ReferenceID] AND [SZL].[ReferenceType] = 'View ZoomMeeting'
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Session] [S] (NOLOCK) ON dbo.SubStractZoomLink([S].[ZoomLink]) = [ZML].[ZoomMeetingID]
```

Query result

```
SessionID   Title           StartTime               EndTime                 Difference
3067        Summit Kick-off 2021-04-15 12:49:52.413 2021-04-15 12:57:54.913 0 Hrs 08 Min 02 Sec
3067        Summit Kick-off 2021-04-15 13:00:41.950 2021-04-15 13:05:14.643 0 Hrs 04 Min 033 Sec
```

Expected query result

```
SessionID   Title           StartTime               EndTime                 Difference
3067        Summit Kick-off 2021-04-15 13:00:41.950 2021-04-15 13:05:14.643 0 Hrs 12 Min 035 Sec
```

Comment: Looks like you need a `GROUP BY` query and `SUM()` on `DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime)`. The problem is with your `datetime_difference()` function, the input are `datetime`. it is not suitable for this. You can create a new function that convert total seconds into the required `Hrs-Min-Sec` format

Comment: Thanks, @Squirrel I'll check do you need `datetime_difference()` logic?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). At the very least, use the current (not deprecated syntax).

Comment: Thanks, @SMor will remove the `NOLOCK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation.  If you want the maximum end time minus the maximum start time, then you can use:

```
SELECT [S].[SessionID], [S].[Title],
       MIN([SZL].[StartTime]), MAX([ SZL].[EndTime]),
       [dbo].[datetime_difference](MIN([SZL].[StartTime]), MAX([SZL].[EndTime])) as [Difference]        
FROM [dbo].[SessionZoomLog] SZL JOIN
     [dbo].[ZoomMeetingLog] ZML
     ON [ZML].[ZoomMeetingLogID] = [SZL].[ReferenceID] AND
        [SZL].[ReferenceType] = 'View ZoomMeeting' JOIN
     [dbo].[Session] [S]
     ON dbo.SubStractZoomLink([S].[ZoomLink]) = [ZML].[ZoomMeetingID] 
GROUP BY [S].[SessionID], [S].[Title];
```

This becomes trickier if you want to add up the times separately.  In that case, the last expression should be:

```
[dbo].[datetime_difference](CONVERT(datetime, 0),
                            DATEADD(second, 
                                    SUM(DATEDIFF(second, [SZL].[StartTime], [SZL].[EndTime])),
                                    CONVERT(datetime, 0)
                                   )
                           ) as [Difference]
```

Notes:

- Your code has a lot of user-defined functions.  That is just going to slow down the query, particularly when used as `JOIN` conditions.
- Don't use `NOLOCK` unless you really understand what it is doing.  Hint:  It allows the reading of inaccurate data, which is usually not desirable.
- Your query escapes all the identifiers which is totally unnecessary.  The clutter causes no harm but it makes the query harder to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting

```
SessionID   Title           StartTime               EndTime                 Difference
3067        Summit Kick-off 2021-04-15 13:00:41.950 2021-04-15 13:05:14.643 0 Hrs 12 Min 035 Sec
```

or this

```
SessionID   Title           StartTime               EndTime                 Difference
3067        Summit Kick-off 2021-04-15 12:49:52.413 2021-04-15 13:05:14.643 0 Hrs 12 Min 035 Sec
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I just want the `Difference` columns to `sum` the value nothing else if `SessionID` same.